# Supplied javaHome is not a valid folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-home

I have migrated a workspace to a new machine with a different java distribution.
The old machine had java-11-openjdk-amd64.
The new one has only corretto.

Upon opening the old workspace on the new machine I get some `problem`s, such as

> Supplied javaHome is not a valid folder. You supplied: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
> line 0 Gradle Error Marker

So in the workspace I deleted `.metadata` and I searched the workspace (and `~/.eclipse`, `~/.gradle` just in case) for references to the old version with

`grep -r "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-o"`

There are no results.
I have made sure that no eclipse processes are running (`ps -aux | grep eclipse`) and restarted eclipse, but the errors remain. What else can I do before creating new project and manually copying the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the right place to edit this is in the eclipse preferences, and/or that eclipse is picking this up from an erroneously set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Window > Preferences > search the filterbox for 'installed' to get to 'Installed JREs', remove any entries that don't seem right and add your coretto install here.

Next check Window > Preferences > Gradle > Arguments > Java Home, and fix things here. Most likely you can just select 'workspace JRE' and that should fix the problem.

If that doesn't work out, there's always the option of adding to your `~/.gradle` file a single line with:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/coretto
```

Comment: In Eclipse, I found a stale cached java.home property in .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs -- you can change it to your new JAVA_HOME or you can remove Gradle nature from the project and apply it again

Answer (score 0):

I received an update to my VM and the previous Pref>Gradle>Arg>Java Home no longer existed.  I cut and pasted in one that did... Unfortunately, this did not work. I had to come through Eclipse and use the file navigation to get to the new Java Home I wanted to use. (Then do a Gradle>Refresh Gradle Project to get it to take).